# flash tcp connection

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Good afternoon

How to use TCP/IP connection to server from flash? 
I use ActionScript 3 and Flash CS4.
I want to put module on site, which connects to server and get fresh info from it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is more of what you are looking for...Perhaps you can post some code where you're to attempt making a TCP/IP connection -- that may help people understand more about what you want to do.

If you are looking for TCP/IP Socket connection, here's a link from the Flex 4 docs about the class, `flash.net.Socket`

http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/net/Socket.html#includeExamplesSummary

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Electroserver](http://www.electrotank.com/es5.html) right now. Code-wise, it's basically a wrapper for a few different protocols, including RTMP and binary TCP. It's kind of a lot of overhead to install, so it may be more than you need, but it works well with Flash.